# Trying to change a CSS Property value with jQuery, What did I do wrong?

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$('#id_body_text').keypress(function(){

    if(this.value.length > 252){
        return false;
    }
    $(".suggest7").html("Remaining characters : " +(252 - this.value.length));
    $(".suggest7").attr('margin-left', "400px");
    $(".suggest7").attr('width', '162px');
});
</script>
```

margin-left and width have completely different values and the code above does not seem to be changing them?  Did I do something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the CSS then use

```
$(".suggest7").css('margin-left', "400px");
$(".suggest7").css('width', '162px');
```

You can even do it in one shot:

```
$(".suggest7").css({'margin-left': "400px",'width':'162px' });
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I misread the jQuery documentation.  Works fine now.